# Using npm as a task runner/build tool - having problems with some cli modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, eslint

I'm trying to use npm as a task runner/build tool after reading this article:

[How to use npm as a build tool](http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/)

and while I'm having some success, I'm stuck on one thing. When running a command-line global tool like JSLINT, JSHINT, or ESLINT, npm will always show the Exit 1 code in the console window:

[image]

As you can see, the command works fine, but npm sees it as an error and displays the error log info. Is this normal and/or is there a way to turn it off for specific commands?

Additional info: this is script block in my package.json config:

"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./src/server/index.js",
    "test": "",
    "lint": "eslint index.js"
  }

then from npm cli I type:

```
npm run lint
```

This will execute the script found in the package.json file with the label: 'lint'

Comment: This should be a great read for you: http://substack.net/task_automation_with_npm_run

Answer (score 3):

I use this:

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "node ./src/server/index.js",
   "lint": "eslint index.js || exit 0"
}
```

Regards!

Answer (score 2):

Since there are validation errors, eslint exists with an Exit code 1, which makes npm believe that there was an error during it's execution.

If you're using linux, you can use this trick to always return an Exit code 0 :

```
"scripts": { "start": "node ./src/server/index.js", "test": "", "lint": "eslint index.js; true" }
```

Comment: I'm using the cli so that true flag does not work in that context.

Comment: Sorry, I see that's a Linux command. My dev env is Windows, so I think it's best using the --silent flag. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

NPM scripts are designed to work this way on purpose, so that an exit code of 1 or 2, (anything other than `0`), will prevent post tasks from running, in the same way it would operate on your operating system.

Using the `--silent` flag *is* an option, but can become an issue where there are other problems with the script, and you will wind up banging your head against a wall when your builds start failing without any lint/test errors.

The best thing to do here... is to configure your process so that it doesn't output an error exit code in situations where you don't want it to. In this case... you have some errors popping up legitimately based on your eslint config. This will cause an error exit code, and (rightfully so) prevent the next task from running. This is actually *very useful* when you're using npm scripts, because you can prevent testing/build steps to be run unecessarily when you know there are errors.

So, in this case, you want to add an `.eslintrc` file to your project, and specify some rules that will both take care of the linting errors, as well as the npm errors.

I've posted a quick sample `.eslintrc` file below. When running `eslint` on the command line, it will automatically detect any `.eslintrc` or `.eslintignore` files, and abide by their configurations.

That sample below will clean up your linting erros, but keep in mind, it changes the exit code that would be thrown when eslint picks up that "trigger". When I change a rule to `0`, it means that it won't alert you when it recognizes that pattern.

You can read more about utilizing and [configuring rule codes](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-rules), or... check out a seed project I have created that uses npm as a build tool, and includes eslint usage: [react-flux-npm-automation](https://github.com/LongLiveCHIEF/react-flux-npm-automation)

```
// /path/to/project/.eslintrc
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "env":{
        "browser":true,
        "node":true,
        "es6":true
    },
    "rules": {
        "strict":0,
        "quotes":0,
        "no-unused-vars":0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found a work-around for this problem. In the scripts block, I use the test script to call the npm command for lint with the --silent flag:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "node ./src/server/index.js",
"test": "npm run-script --silent lint",
"lint": "eslint index.js"}
```

Then on the command-line I can type:

```
npm run test
```

Now it's working without showing the error log.